# how to create unique keyword in the oracle db?

Tags: oracle, autocomplete, oracle10g

i am using autocomplete with oracle Db,how to create unique keyword for the table.

KEYWORD                                            VARCHAR2(100)
 COUNT                                              NUMBER(18)

how can i make as unique

can plz tell the query

Comment: you've received something like 40+ answers to your 16 questions, but have only accepted one of them. Please remember to accept answers!

Comment: What has [autocomplete] got to do with anything?

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE mytable add CONSTRAINT keyword_unique UNIQUE (keyword);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
create table "unique keyword" ("KEYWORD" VARCHAR2(100), "COUNT" NUMBER(18));
```

I think that will do the trick ;-)